# send ether to a contract and then to my address

Tags: web3js, ether, wallets, contract-invocation, wallet-transfer

I am implementing a website where the user makes a purchase, at that moment I create a contract and transfer the money to this contract along with a description of the purchase and then process it in the back end, the user pays for the product and the gas. I would then like to withdraw this money from the backend and send it to my address but without me having to pay gas for this. is this possible? what option would you recommend? the problem I have is that I can verify the transaction from the back end that is done from the front end, but I don't know what products the user bought, I only know how much I paid for this product and I understand that the way I can store the payment and the products is through a contract to then call the contract from the back end and see all the complete information and be able to store this information in my database, but I don't know if when I send the contract money to my address I will be charged gas. Thank you very much for your help, I do not know if I am focusing the solution wrong, I would appreciate your opinion. my website is in web js and the back end is in php with ethereum tx and web3p

Comment: the products are virtual so the price varies between each product, that is why I need to know what product the user bought and how much he paid for it and thus activate it in the database, is there any other way to store the product information without create a contract?

Comment: Why are you creating a contract for every purchase? I think you could create one contract and make the contract forward the received ether to your wallet.